# как перезапустить массив в цикле с обнулением?

Tags: java

есть 2 переменные!

```
int iMa = 12000;
int Ma[250];

 for(int qt = 0; qt < 250; qt++)
     {
      Ma[qt] = iMa + qt;
     }
```

Помогите сделать следующее! Надо, что бы после 250 переборов, цикл обнулил переменную iMa обратно на 12000 и начал заново! Желательно бесконечно!

Comment: ну напишите второй цикл, какие проблемы?

Comment: А зачем ее "обнулять обратно на 12000"? Она что, где-то изменяется, что ее нужно снова и снова "обнулять обратно на 12000"?

Comment: Ну и надо больше восклицательных знаков.

Answer (score 2):

```
int iMa;
int Ma[250];
while (true) {
  iMa = 12000; // обнуляем iMa на 12000
  for(int qt = 0; qt < 250; qt++) {
    Ma[qt] = iMa + qt;
  }
}
```